# Gibberish data using npgsql from windows using utf8.en_us encode

Tags: c#, postgresql, utf-8

I developed a .net program to retrieve data through an api and import the data into postgresql database with utf8 encode hosted on AWS RDS.

The problem is that I developed the code on a windows machine with gb2312(active page code: 936) but I deployed the program on a windows server with utf8.en_us(active page code:437) on AWS. The application running on my machine can correctly store Chinese characters into database and displays well. But it turns out to import Gibberish data into database when running on server.

I tried to do a conversion directly on string within the code, like this:

```
private string Utf8y(string a)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(a));
}
```

But it's in vain.

Any idea or solution on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out a solution:

Go to `control panel -> language, time, location` blabla, change your non-unicode encoding to Chinese(Simplified).

Should work with other languages too.